# Can't access the value of the `to` form field

Tags: python, django, web

I'm creating a blog using Django and there's this feature I implemented that allows users to share posts via email.

Here's the `form`

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder' : 'your name'}
    ))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder' : 'your email'}
    ))
    to = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder' : 'recipient\'s email'}
    ))
    comments = forms.CharField(max_length=500, required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'rows' : 5, 'placeholder' : 'Tell recipient what you think about this post (optional)'}
    ), help_text='The maximum length of the text is 4000')
```

Here's the `view`

```
def post_share(request, post_id):
    # Retrieve the post by id
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, status='published')
    sent = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Form was submitted
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Form fields passed validation
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
            presubject = '{} ({}) recommends you reading "{}"'
            subject = presubject.format(cd['name'], cd['email'], post.title)
            premessage = 'Read "{}" at {}\n\n{}\'s comments: {}'
            message = premessage.format(post.title, post_url, cd['name'], cd['comments'])
            send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@sayc.com', [cd['to']])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    return render(request, 'post_share.html', {'post' : post, 'form' : form, 'sent' : sent})
```

Here's the `url`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/share/$', views.post_share, name='post_share'),
]
```

And here's the `template`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Share a Post - {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="mt-4 row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10">
            <div class="card">
                {% if sent %}
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        <h3>Email Successfully Sent</h3>
                        <p class="lead">"{{ post.title }}" was successfully sent to {{ cd.to }}</p>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title text-center">Share "{{ post.title }}" by email</h3>                            
                        <form action="." method="post" novalidate>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% include 'includes/form.html' %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Share</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

It works fine but whenever I send an email, the template is supposed to return what's in the `if` block of the template. What's bugging me is the fact that `{{ cd.to }}` (appended at the end of the success message in the template) doesn't return any value. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not passed `cd` to the template, so it cannot put that value.
Instead of `{{cd.to}}` you can use `{{form.data.to}}` to show value from form itself.